# Installing PHP on linux

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php5

I'm trying to setup php with oci8 support. I think I've configured all correctly before starting with oci, here is how I tried to start the install :

```
./configure -prefix=/common_share/APACHE/server --with-apxs2=/common_share/APACHE/server/bin/apxs ./configure --with-oci8=instantclient,/common_share/APACHE/oracle-cli --with-libxml-dir=/common_share/APACHE/libxml --with-config-file-path=/common_share/APACHE/php/php.ini
```

I don't have root access so I have to install all manually. Anyways the error I get after I start `make install` is :

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /common_share/APACHE/oracle-cli/libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

And I just have no idea what went wrong there nor what to do next. Anyone had similar issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `clntsh` library is a 32 bit and you system 64 bit(or reverse case), you have to make sure the library is compiled for the same architecture as the one you are currently running or `ld` won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually "make install" script require "root" access ...simply because it copy some files in some system directories
On which distro, you are running ?
Have you write access to "/common_share/APACHE/" ?

Can't you ask to the administrator of the machine to install php for you ?